# Is there a way to get headers from an url in python?

Tags: python, http-headers

Is there a way to get the headers from url in any format like charles proxy does in python.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? A URL doesn't have headers, but HTTP requests and responses do. Are you receiving a request, or a response, or are you wanting to set headers on one of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get headers from an URL in Python programming language. The requests module provides a way to do this.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.google.com"
response = requests.head(url)
print(response.headers) # prints the entire header as a dictionary
print(response.headers["Content-Length"]) # prints a specific section of the 
dictionary
```

https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/python-get-response-headers-with-code-examples/